# Reading XML and looping

Tags: xml, vb.net

Hey all i have an XML file that i am trying to loop though. My current code does this just fine BUT it only does it for the first 2 nodes. It repeats nodes over and over again.

My XML structor is like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
 <stn1110>
    <jobid>-87</jobid>
    <sn_siab>677 6086tyhg67y</sn_siab>
    <jobid>-35667</jobid>
    <sn_siab>677 63436hyh</sn_siab>
    <jobid>-357689</jobid>
    <sn_siab>677 87888888</sn_siab>
    <jobid>-50000</jobid>
    <sn_siab>677 gdfr4365454</sn_siab>
    <jobid>-366877</jobid>
    <sn_siab>677 nfrrt444445</sn_siab>
 </stn1110>
```

And my currrent VB.net code is this:

```
    Dim file As String = "C:\bin\Debug\stn1110.xml"

    Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument
    Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
    Dim m_node As XmlNode

    m_xmld = New XmlDocument()
    m_xmld.Load(file)
    MessageBox.Show(m_xmld.OuterXml)
    m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("/stn1110")

    For Each m_node In m_nodelist
        Dim firstNameValue = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText
        Dim lastNameValue = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText

        Debug.Print(firstNameValue)
        Debug.Print(lastNameValue)
    Next
```

How can i loop through the whole thing while still gathing only the 2 childnodes every loop?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your m_nodelist contains only one entry, because there is only one `stn1110` node.

What you probably want is to output its 0+1-st child in the first loop iteration, its 2+3-rd child in the second iteration, etc. Thus, you could do something like this:

```
Dim m_node = m_xmld.SelectSingleNode("/stn1110")

For i = 0 To m_node.ChildNodes.Count - 1 Step 2
    Dim firstNameValue = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(i).InnerText
    Dim lastNameValue = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(i+1).InnerText

    Debug.Print(firstNameValue)
    Debug.Print(lastNameValue)
Next i
```

<sub>(Hooray, finally some use case for the `Step` keyword!)</sub>